# Is it a good idea to pass paramter repository to ViewModel instead of inherited from AndroidViewModel?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack

The Code A is from https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/PagingWithNetworkSample

The Code B is from https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/PagingSample

I know I should use `AndroidViewModel` instead of `ViewModel` when I need to use `Context` to instance a database based Room, just like Code B.

I find the class `SubRedditViewModel` in Code A doesn't inherited from `AndroidViewModel`, it pass the paramter `repository` using construction function.

Is it a good idea to pass paramter `repository` to `ViewModel` instead of inherited from `AndroidViewModel` ?

**Code A**

```
class SubRedditViewModel(
        private val repository: RedditPostRepository,
        private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {
   ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
class CheeseViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
    val dao = CheeseDb.get(app).cheeseDao()
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moment you inherit `AndroidViewModel`, your class becomes less unit-testable, as you depend on the Android framework. Also, in your snippet Code B, you lost the ability to inject a test double for your `dao`, making testing even harder.

In conclusion, try to avoid using framework classes and practice dependency injection (manually or with the aid of a DI framework like Dagger, it doesn't matter). So your snippet Code A would be preferable.

Comment: Is testing really harder? Maybe consider using an in-memory Room implementation, that way you get real behavior even in tests, which is actually totally ok.

Comment: I was referring to unit testing. You are speaking of integration testing, which I agree, it has its own benefits, but it doesn't substitute the first (see testing pyramid).